# Scrape links from HTML

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing, scrape

I have been always using `preg_match` to scrape URLs from HTML files but I wanted to extract only URLs that have `.mp3` as their extension. I was told to try DOM and I have been trying to fix a code but it doesn't work. I get a blank page whatever I do.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://www.mp3olimp.net/miley-cyrus-when-i-look-at-you/';
    $html = @file_get_html($url);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc); 
    $links = $xpath->query('//a[ends-with(@href, ".mp3")]/@href');

    echo $links;
?>
```

Comment: What happens with print_r($links) instead of echo?

Comment: @MalcolmDiggs the result is the same, a blank page

Comment: Well the first thing I would do is remove the @ sign from @file_get_html. Prepending the @ just suppresses errors, but in this case, you WANT to see errors, so you might as well remove it and let the script tell you what's going wrong.

Comment: You need to do basic troubleshooting, that means, understand how PHP errors and where you can obtain more information about errors. See as well: [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/367456)

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of problems!

- As noted, remove `@` before `file_get_html()` to see the errors.
- `file_get_contents($url)` will work to get the HTML contents.
- Typo, `$dom =` should be `$doc =`
- Another annoying point, the HTML source is fairly malformed, leading to later errors.
- `ends-with()` is only supported in XPath 2.0, PHP uses XPath 1.0.  So you'll have to find another way to check the ending.  A bit of regex should do the trick.

Comment: Be sure to use proper code formatting to make your answer easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for this!  Just getting into this whole StackOverflow thing. Long time reader, first time poster (cliche, I know).

Comment: You're welcome. Make sure to read the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and have a look at the options the editor offers you. That way it should be easy to write some good answers and gain reputation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = file_get_contents($url);    
$regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?.mp3)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";
if(preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $input, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
  foreach($matches as $match) {
    // $match[2] = link address
    // $match[3] = link text
  }
}
```